# How to get insertRows source?

Tags: c++, qt

I am instrumenting a model/view for item rearrangement and I am failing to understand how to override the `insertRows` method. Just for practice I am trying to wrap a `std::vector` with a custom structure.

```
std::vector<aStruct> mD;//my data
bool insertRows(int start, int rows, const QModelIndex & parent)
{
    auto i = parent.row();
    cout <<"I going to " << start << ":" << rows << " choosing "<< i<< endl;
    beginInsertRows(parent, start, start + rows - 1);
    aStruct blank(0);// Should be the value of the item being moved?
    mD.insert(mD.begin()+start,blank);
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a place to get at element that gives me a hold of the item being moved. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use next steps to insert rows:

```
1. Call beginInsertRows
2. Modify your internal data structure
3. Call endInsertRows
```

There is all Ok in your sample.

View will insert empty rows (as @Riateche told) and will **fill it automatically**, after call of `endInsertRows`. All that you need is to override `YourModel::data` method to return correct data from you mD structure.

View will call `YourModel::data` method immediately after inserting empty rows. You don't need to do any extra operations. View will care about "filling" it.

Overriding of `YourModel::setData` method is mostly used for interaction between view and model, when user want to change data throught view widget.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `mD` and `insertRows` are members of a custom model class.

`insertRows` doesn't receive any information about contents of inserted rows. Empty values should be inserted. Rows should be filled with data in the `setData` virtual method implementation.